# Why doesn't distinct work in the run method of my query class?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I want to get a distinct set of results based on an entity property.  I am trying to run the following code.

```
db.Query(EntityName, projection = ("entityProperty",)).run(distinct=True)
```

I get the following error

```
Unknown configuration option ('distinct')
```

According to the GAE documentation distinct is part of the run method

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_run

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your query.

Are you using GAE dev server 1.7.4? It should be ok with that version.

Comment: Thats it actually.  As of 1.7.4 "DISTINCT for Datastore queries is now available as an experimental feature."  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Comment: It occurred to me because I tried to reproduce your problem on my old dev machine and had the same issue because it was not updated. . Hope you are good to go now.